# Spring Data Cassandra: Autowiring of Interface failed

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

```
package lokesh.repository;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import com.model.User;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface UserOverview extends Repository<User, Integer>{

    @Query("select count(*) from users where name = :userName ")
    int overview(@Param("userName") String userName);

}
```

**service**

```
package lokesh.service;

public UserService(){
    @Autowired
    private UserOverview userOverview; //Injection of autowired dependencies failed
}
```

**Main**

```
package lokesh;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class UserApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UserApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am trying to a write a custom query. so i created an interface extending spring data repository. i want to use that interface in service class to invoke the method in that interface. I got dependency failed exception. can someone spot my mistake

Comment: `@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository` is not required on your repository. As soon as you have a Spring Data Module (like Spring Data Cassandra) on your classpath, it will be picked up. Autowiring may also occur because of infrastructure issues (connection failed, missing table) so it would be helpful to see the whole stack trace.

Comment: I cannot post stacktrace for some reason. but it is because of "nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException". There are some other beans in the same directory which are scanned by spring. Can spring instantiate a interface by itself?

Comment: Spring Data creates a proxy implementing the interface and provides that instance as bean.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to separate between your `@Configuration` class and the rest of application, in your case the class with the main method.

Within the `@Configuration` class you should mark your beans to be injected with `@Bean` annotation, in order be able to inject them.

However, you do have `@Repository` annotation which is the bean you're trying to auto wire, I assume.

**Try to add a package String in `@ComponentScan` so it can identify your `@Repository` class as eligible bean for auto wiring.** Like this:

```
@ComponentScan("com.package.to.scan")
```

***On the other hand, an interface can't serve as bean, it's not an actual instance. be aware.***

Answer (score 0):

In your UserApplication class, you are using the ComponentScan annotation without providing any explicit package name.

**Try providing the package name of UserOverview class.**
Like this:

```
@ComponentScan("lokesh.repository")
```